# CSS div table advertising row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, row

I have a div table like this:

```
<div class="dTable">
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
   </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>
```

So i need to put advertisement row between -for example- 2nd and 3th rows like this:

```
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dAdvCell">Advertisement codes</div>
   </div>
```

- And i know that div tables don't support colspan/rowspan.
- I can't seperate table. Because i am ordering table records with js.
- And i can't use display: table-caption. Because i need to put between two
  rows.

Edit:I need to inject full width. This is not duplicated question. display: table-caption not worked for me.

So what is your suggestion for this issue.
Thanks...

**SOLVED**: I solved this issue like this:

```
<div class="dTable">
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dRow adv_row"><div class="dAdvCell">Advertisement Codes</div>
      <div class="dCell"></div>
      <div class="dCell"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
   </div>
   <div class="dRow">
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
      <div class="dCell">bla bla bla</div>
   </div>
   .
   .
   .
</div>

.adv_row{height: 90px; //your advertisement height}
.dAdvCell{position: absolute; width: 728px; height: 90px; //adv dimensions}
```

**Again I insist that; this is not a duplicated question. And nobody has solved like this. C-U :)**

Comment: What is the question? ... How to make that injected full width?

Comment: Use `insertAfter()`

Comment: @LGSon Yes exactly.

Comment: @Mohammad jQuery insertAfter is limiting width with previous row's cell too.